# How do I access the first character of a string in Rust?

Tags: rust

In JavaScript, I'd write:

```
s.charAt(0)
```

What would it be in Rust? How should I handle the `s.length == 0` case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `s.chars().next()`. This will return `None` if the string is empty or `Some(c)` otherwise.